# how to lower the LTC3780's voltage

Tags: power-supply, voltage, buck

So I bought the LTC3780 Step Up/Down Constant Voltage Power Supply from a cheap chinese store on Aliexpress. The page said 1v-32v at a max of 10amps. Although, when I received it and tested it today, it only could go as low as 5v. Then checking other stores on the internet they all had it listed at 5v-32v. I opened a dispute with Aliexpress who said they could do nothing. So with that said is there anyway I can lower the output voltage by about 4v at all times?

Comment: You bought a powersupply using the LTC3780, or bought an LTC3780? 1V-32V input, or output?

Comment: Linear Tech on Aliexpress? Faaaaaaaake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LTC3780 output voltage is set by an external feedback resistive divider carefully placed across the output capacitor.

The resultant feedback signal is compared with the internal precision 0.800V voltage reference by the error amplifier.

This is controlled by the R ratio from Vout to the *Vout sense* pin 6.
You can start by exploring these values.

\$V_{out}=0.8V (1+\frac{R_2}{R_{1}})\$

Comment: I agree with Tony; either throw it in the bin and buy something from a reputable supplier or investigate the feedback components. Either way learn something from this about cheap suppliers - on average, they cost you more!

Comment: Thank you very much, though I probably won't stop buying cheap ;)